# removing uncessary keys in result mongoose

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I am currently getting a response in mongoose like this

```
    {
        "_id" : "5a0be40836341c8ef9dc6d9d",
        "Username" : "Adkins Daugherty",
        "ContactDetail" : {
            "ApiID" : "5a0be408ed6983954888bdb5",
            "ContactName" : "Pace Roach",
        }
}
```

But i want like this :

```
    {
        "_id" : "5a0be40836341c8ef9dc6d9d",
        "Username" : "Adkins Daugherty",
        "ApiID" : "5a0be408ed6983954888bdb5",
        "ContactName" : "Pace Roach",
}
```

How can i do this using  mongoose. My collection name is **contacts**

Thanks

EDIT-1

```
db.contacts.aggregate([{ 
        $match: { Username: 'year_Adkins Daugherty' } },
        { "$unwind": "$ContactDetail" },
        { 
            "$group": { "_id": "$_id",
                        "ApiID": "$ContactDetail.ApiID" 
                    }
        }
    ])
```

Comment: Getting a response from doing what? Probably a populate result, but you really need to show people. MongoDB `.find()` queries ( which is all populate is really using ) do not "alter the shape" of the documents in result. If you expect the response from the server to do that you use `.aggregate()`, or otherwise 're-shape' the results you receive yourself in code after they are returned.

Comment: This is simple .find() query result. I tried .aggregate(), but could not achieve the desired output.

Comment: You tried what? No code in your question buddy. Show what you actually tried and what the data actually looks like as stored in MongoDB.

Comment: Please see Edit-1

Comment: So where did you find to do that? How about searching for ["mongodb reshape document"](https://www.google.com/search?q=mongodb+reshape+document), or was my usage of those words earlier too obtuse?

Comment: @NeilLunn, on your given link, I tried $project & found a solution that works for me. I have posted it as answer. It is in mongoose (expressjs). Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think I got an answer in $project

```
return Contact.aggregate(
        [
            { $match: { Username: regex } },
            {
            $project:{
                    Username:1,
                    ApiID:"$ContactDetail.ApiID",
                    Name:"$ContactDetail.ContactName",
                    ProfileImageUrl:"$ContactDetail.ProfileImageUrl",
                    OutletName:"$ContactDetail.OutletName"

                }
            }
        ]
    ).exec()
```

The result I got is

```
{
        "_id": "5a0be40836341c8ef9dc6d9d",
        "Username": "year_Adkins Daugherty",
        "ApiID": "5a0be408ed6983954888bdb5",
        "Name": "Pace Roach",
        "ProfileImageUrl": "http://placehold.it/256x256",
        "OutletName": "Codehow___kjvolyi3ye"
    }
```